# Prevent calculation inside JSX from rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Maybe I am missing something here but I want to do `{(dataIndex = dataIndex + 1)}` inside some JSX.

I have two nested maps which are pulling together table header and table rows. I need to give each field a unique tabIndex.

Here is a simplified version =>

```
let dataIndex = 0;
const rows = data.map((row, index) => {
    return (
      <tr >
        <td />
            {columns.map((column, index2) => {
            return (
                <td tabIndex={dataIndex}>
                {(dataIndex = dataIndex + 1)}
                </td>
                );
            }
        </tr>
    );
}))
```

Ive knocked this together really quickly its not exactly the same and I have abstracted out the bits which dont matter. I just dont understand why `dataIndex` is being displayed in each data field

Comment: You have `index2` it's unique index of element in array, you can use it instead of `dataIndex`.

Comment: This doesnt work, it goes over the first row and then skips til my pagination. Are there any other factors which could cause this? Index2 is not unique as it gives all of column 1 the same tabIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was a misunderstanding of `tabIndex`. I just needed to set every `<td/>` element to have a tab index of 0, meaning that they would be found by the keyboard.

It was actually just skipping over the table.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to avoid **JSX** calculation Printing to web page is using `<noscript></noscript>` **tags** around the function

> `<noscript>{your calculation}</noscript>`